# toLocaleDateString() - issue with Norwegian

Tags: javascript, reactjs, locale

I have an issue with getting locale datestring correctly formatted. It suddenly stopped working for Norwegian. I've tried 'no-NO' and 'nb-NO'. Any ideas about what could be causing this? I'm stuck.

Example:

```
console.log(new Date().toLocaleDateString('no-NO', {month: 'long', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric'}))
// 2021 M08 10
```

Other languages work as expected:

```
console.log(new Date().toLocaleDateString('da-DK', {month: 'long', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric'}))
// 10. august 2021
```

Comment: What is your expected result? In my local, it says **August 11, 2021**

Comment: Which browser are you using? Firefox supports `nb` and `nb-NO` but Chrome doesn't support either `nb` nor `no` locales.

Comment: It should be 10. august 2021 in Norwegian. I'm using Edge, and it worked before there. It also worked in Chrome a couple of weeks ago. Very strange.

Comment: Fixed in Chrome now, but not in Edge 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug in chrome causing this, hopefully they will fix it soon. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1215606